# Restore SQL Server 2008 db without affecting users

Tags: sql-server-2008, restore, users, database-restore, orphans

When I restore a db in Sql Server 2008 R2 from data on another server, it makes a mess of the users. I have a Windows User and MsSql Login named Web_SqlA on both machines. Before the Restore, Web_SqlA is properly mapped to the right Windows user in the database. After the Restore, Web_SqlA is still listed as a user for the db, but it's no longer tied to the Windows user, causing Trusted Connections to it to fail.

How can I Restore the db without breaking this user each time?

I see that this:
[Sql Server Database Restore](https://serverfault.com/questions/268935/sql-server-database-restore)

Addresses fixing these orphaned users after the fact; I'm looking to prevent overwriting the users during the Restore in the first place - everything else should be restored, but leave my users be. How can I go about that?

Comment: Looks like both of those links point to the same question - are they supposed to be different?

Comment: Ah - yes, thanks, clearly pasted one link twice. I'll edit to leave just the one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use sp_help_revlogin before doing the restore, this will allow the users to match up with the logins. It'll take a little bit of planning...

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/246133

Comment: Thanks! That article is for 2005; this appears to be updated for 2008: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/918992 After copy/pasting that updated sp_help_revlogin code in to add it to master's SP's, I was able to generate the command(s) for recreating users after the fact. Since the Restore creates broken versions of these same users, I needed to prepend the generated script with: drop login [Web_SqlA]; etc, to clean out the broken logins the Restore creates before replacing them with fixed users.

Comment: This modified version of the SP apparently uses a simplified syntax for these Windows users that get corrupted: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lcris/archive/2006/04/03/567680.aspx For example it changes the login creation to simply CREATE LOGIN (user) FROM WINDOWS